# Modelling a partially-loaded related object in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm redoing a model library and hoped someone smarter than me could help me solve one annoyance from my previous implementation.

Say I have a series of related models like this:

```
class Pond {
  let pk: Int
  let depth: Int
}
class Frog {
  let pk: Int
  let name: String
  let pond: Pond
}
```

The objects are loaded from a store. Let's say I picked up a Frog. It's got a primary key, and it belongs to a Pond. I'll get JSON like this:

```
{"pk": 42, "name": "Kermit", "pond_pk": 1}
```

So, I know everything about the Frog, and I know which Pond it belongs to, but I don't know (nor need to know) the depth of that Pond. This means I can't instantiate a Pond object yet.

Here's the solutions I've considered:

1) Double-up every relationship property. Such as:

```
class Frog {
  let pond: Pond?
  let pondPk: Int
}
```

This doesn't seem good at all.

2) Similar to above, but make an Optional-ish struct to handle a relationship.

```
struct Relationship {
  let pk: Int
  let object: AnyObject?
}
class Frog {
  let pond: Relationship
}
```

and then test for `frog.pond.object` but this is very verbose.

3) Double up every class with a 'stub' version so the relation can be a PondStub or a Pond (if fully loaded).

```
class PondStub {
  let pk: Int
}
class Pond: PondStub {
  let depth: Int
}
class FrogStub {
  let pk: Int
}
class Frog: FrogStub {
  let name: String
  let pond: PondStub
}
```

4) Give up and implement every non-`pk` property as an implicitly-unwrapped Optional and check for `nil` whenever I'm not positive I've loaded the related object.

```
class Pond {
  let pk: Int
  let depth: Int!
}
```

This is what I've done since Swift 1. It's worked, except I'm losing all the benefits of the Optional class. It's like I'm fighting Swift rather than using it properly.

Any better ideas would be greatly appreciated.

PS: This will be intended for Swift on Linux.

**Edit:** I had another idea overnight, echoed by dfri's comment below (which ought to be an answer!) I like everything about it, except that it's hard to model relationships between objects if they aren't saved to a Store (for example, when creating new objects).

```
// The model objects are still very simple.
struct Pond {
    let pk: Int?
    let depth: Int
}
struct Frog {
    let pk: Int?
    let name: String
    let pondPk: Int?

}

// There is a separate Store module which co-ordinates the objects
// and their relationships.
protocol Storable {
    static var hash: String { get }
    var pk: Int? { get }
}
extension Storable {
    var hash: String? {
        get {
            guard let pk = self.pk else { return nil }
            return self.dynamicType.hash + String(pk)
        }
    }
}
class Store {
    var contents: [String: Storable] = [:]
    func add(obj: Storable) {
        guard let hash = obj.hash else { return }
        contents[hash] = obj
    }
    func fetch(type: Storable.Type, withPk pk: Int) -> Storable? {
        let hash = type.hash + String(pk)
        return contents[hash]
    }
}
// This module also handles easy lookups between the models.
extension Pond: Storable {
    static let hash = "Pond"
}
extension Frog: Storable {
    static let hash = "Frog"
    func pond(fromStore store: Store) -> Pond? {
        guard let pk = pondPk else { return nil }
        return store.fetch(Pond.self, withPk: pk) as? Pond
    }
}

// Example usage.
let store = Store()
let pond = Pond(pk: 1, depth: 4)
store.add(pond)
let frog = Frog(pk: 1, name: "Kermit", pondPk: pond.pk!)
store.add(frog)
if let fetchedPond = frog.pond(fromStore: store) {
    print(fetchedPond.depth) // prints 4
}
```

Comment: How do you store your Ponds (or the info about the, e.g. `depth`) once they are known, a dictionary? E.g., do each single Frog object own it's own Pond instance, or just a reference to the pool of ponds? It seems as if Ponds are unique (from their id:s), so from the above, does Frog necessarily need to contain a Pond object; couldn't they possibly only contain a pond id?

Comment: Yes I thought about that option after posting. There is a central Store with references to everything. I do like the simple notation of frog.pond.depth but I could I suppose add computed properties for each relation. Pop it in as an answer?

Comment: My comment were more of an inquiry than an actual answer (and a light one at that), but I'm glad if it helped you get started :) If your edit above works satisfactory, you could add it as an answer of your own (it's totally OK to add answers to your own questions). Note above that `store.add(pond)` as well as `store.add(frog)` will add _copies_ (value assignment) of these to the store. This means that the following `frog.pond(fromStore: store)` will query the `pond.depth` of a `pond` in `store`, however based on a `Frog` instance that is detached from the assiociated instance in `store`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes `(NX)` regarding your (nice) solution follows.

In the example usage of your edit above (`frog.pond(fromStore: store)`) you work with `Frog` instances that have *copies of themselves* in the `store` instance. I.e.

```
// Example usage.
let store = Store()
let pond = Pond(pk: 1, depth: 4) // (N1)
store.add(pond)
let frog = Frog(pk: 1, name: "Kermit", pondPk: pond.pk!)
store.add(frog)
if let fetchedPond = frog.pond(fromStore: store) { // (N2)
    print(fetchedPond.depth) // prints 4
}
```

Notes:

- `(N1)`: Adds a *copy* of `pond` to `store`. Possibly better to initialize and add the pond in a single step to `store`: `store.add(Pond(pk: 1, depth: 4))`.
- `(N2)`: here you work with an instance of `frog` from which a copy exists (value assignment) in `store`, however not working with the actual copy in `store`.

I.e.

```
var frog = Frog(pk: 1, name: "Kermit", pondPk: pond.pk!)
store.add(frog)
frog.name = "Hermit" // <-- will not effect Kermit frog in store
```

Either you can let your frogs be class types rather than value types, or you can ask yourself if the frogs themselves really need to be stored (or if this is just needed for the ponds?).

---

I'll add an variation of your "storable" solution as posted in your edit above. In this, `Frog` instances are not stored in the central store, but can be used "locally" and access the frog:s associated `Pond` (which are stored in central store) by using a reference to the store. This would be acceptable under the original specifics of your question (*"need to access the `Pond` instance of a `Frog`, but not vice versa"*); however a deal-breaker if you necessarily want to store also all different `Frog` instances in your store.

This could possibly be useful if `Frog`:s are *"on-the-fly"* object whereas ponds are *"larger static entities"*, e.g.; a limited number of ponds will be added to the central store at initialization, whereas `Frog` objects will pop up and go out of scope dynamically during runtime.

**Store module**

This holds for this alternative solution as well as your solution above: no need to the property `pk` be an optional, as all *existing* `Pond` or `Frog` instances should always have an id of their own.

```
protocol Storable {
    static var hash: String { get }
    var pk: Int { get }
}

extension Storable {
    var hash: String {
        get {
            return self.dynamicType.hash + String(pk)
        }
    }
}

class Store {
    var contents: [String: Storable] = [:]
    func add(obj: Storable) {
        contents[obj.hash] = obj
    }
    func fetch(type: Storable.Type, withPk pk: Int) -> Storable? {
        let hash = type.hash + String(pk)
        return contents[hash]
    }
}
```

**Pond and Frog classes**

Since the central store should always be initialized (even if it's empty), we can add a store reference to your `Frog` objects (at initialization). We present this in the context of the alternative solution where only `Pond`:s are storable, whereas `Frog`:s contain a reference to the central store, and via this, can neatly access `Pond` properties (via optional chaining, e.g. `frog.pond?.depth`) for the pond of `Frog`:s `pondPk` property.

```
struct Pond : Storable {
    static let hash = "Pond"
    let pk: Int
    let depth: Int
}

struct Frog {
    let pk: Int
    let name: String
    let pondPk: Int?
    weak var store: Store? // reference to central Store()

    var pond: Pond? {
        guard let pondPk = pondPk else { return nil }
        return store?.fetch(Pond.self, withPk: pondPk) as? Pond
    }
}
```

**Example usage**

```
func printPondDepth(frog: Frog) {
    if let _ = frog.pondPk {
        print(frog.pond?.depth ?? "No pond with id \(frog.pondPk ?? 0) in frog \(frog.name):s associated store")
    }
    else {
        print("No pond id associated with frog \(frog.name)")
    }
}

/* Central store */
let store = Store()

/* Some frogs read prior to any Ponds being added to the store */
let frog = Frog(pk: 1, name: "Kermit", pondPk: 1, store: store)
let anotherFrog = Frog(pk: 2, name: "Mitker", pondPk: 3, store: store)

/* Adding ponds to the store */
store.add(Pond(pk: 1, depth: 4))
store.add(Pond(pk: 4, depth: 25))

/* another frog and some attempts to get the depth of the 
   pond in which a frog possibly resides */
let thirdFrog = Frog(pk: 3, name: "Kerker", pondPk: nil, store: store)

printPondDepth(frog)        /* 4 */
printPondDepth(anotherFrog) /* No pond with id 3 in frog Mitker:s associated store */
printPondDepth(thirdFrog)   /* No pond id associated with frog Kerker */
```

Comment: I intended to come back and make some useful comments re the choice of struct, but I never have the time, so thanks for your great answer and sorry about the delay on the big green tick.

Comment: @tobygriffin no worries. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a lazy variable initialization.  Your example doesn't mention how and if it is possible to get the pond of a frog independently of the frog structure but I have to assume it can otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question.

```
 class Pond 
 {
   let pk: Int       = 0
   let depth: Int    = 0 
 }

 class Frog 
 { 
   let pk: Int         = 0
   let name: String    = ""
   lazy var pond: Pond = Pond() // initialize or get the pond for your frog here
 }
```

The lazy pond variable will only be initialized when you make a reference to it and it will have the full content of the Frog object to work with when it does.

Note: I used Pond() directly to illustrate where you would put the pond loading code but you will most likely need something more specific to the frog instance to actually get the right pond (this is just to illustrate the concept)

[EDIT] added a more explicit example of what is entailed by the use of a lazy var

```
 class Pond 
 {
   static var allPonds:[Int:Pond] = [:]
   static func withKey(key:Int) -> Pond
   {
      if let existingPond = allPonds[key] 
      { return existingPond }
      let newPond = Pond(key)
      allPonds[key] = newPond
      return newPond
   }

   let pk: Int       
   let depth: Int    = 0 

   init(_ key:Int) 
   { 
     // get the pond data from the actual source here
     pk = key 
   } 
 }

 class Frog 
 { 
   let pk: Int         = 0
   let name: String    = ""
   let pondPk:Int      = 0
   lazy var pond: Pond = Pond.withKey(self.pondPk) 
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I need. My Frog only arrives knowing enough about its Pond to be able to look it up later if needed, but I can't initialise the Pond with just its PK unless I make all its properties optional.